# Master Detail object creation using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hello I wanted to know if there is a possibility of using "CreateSalesforceObject" function to create record on a master-detail relation object. We have a detail on Account object and we are not able to retrieve, create, update to that object.
My understanding is that this may not possible, any help/workaround would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your AMPSCRIPT? I do not see any documentation that says it is not possible using CreateSalesforceObject, we might need the master side of the record id created or retrieved first before we attempt to create the child record.

Comment: `code`

%%[ var @rs
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('account_details__c', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'region', '=', 'west')
if RowCount(@rs) == 1 then
set @subscriberRow = Row(@rs, 1)
set @firstName = Field(@subscriberRow, "FirstName") 
endif
]%%

 %%=v(@firstName)=%%
`code`

Comment: I think the problem is in below code, as it tries to retrieve all account_details__c records WHERE "region" is SET to "west". This will/might return potentially many rows, if this was your intention, you need to iterate through these rows to do what you wished to do.
The recommendation is always narrow down your search, maybe compare with an account ID which is unique.
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('account_details__c', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'region', '=', 'west')

Comment: I have tried to hardcode the ID of the record as well, it did not worked either.

Answer (score 0):

```
%%[
var @accountRows,@accountKey
set @accountKey = '0012e000004Nbn7AAC' //hardcoded 18-digit salesforce unique ID existing in your system
set @accountRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
                           'account_details__c',
                           'Id,FirstName,LastName',
                           "Id", "=", @accountKey )

if RowCount(@accountRows) == 1 then
    var @accountRow
    set @accountRow = Row(@accountRows, 1)
    set @firstName = Field(@accountRow, 'FirstName')
    set @lastName = Field(@accountRow, 'LastName')
else
    RaiseError('Account row is not found', true)
endif
]%%

First Name : %%=v(@firstName)=%%
```

Try this code - it should work if you replace with an existing hardcoded ID for account key. And hopefully, there are no integration issues with SF and the custom object permissions within sales cloud.